# New Nuxt3 app is throwing undefined error relating to Nitro proxy

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have been working on Nuxt2 for a while, and so I thought I would give 3 a try. After I finish the installation instructions found here: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation I am getting the following error when I run a local server:
 `ERROR  [uncaughtException] proxyReq.appendHeader is not a function`.
It appears to be related to the nitro engine that Nuxt is using:

```
  at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (/C:/Users/cards/Documents/job-hunt/job-site/node_modules/nitropack/dist/chunks/server.mjs:329:18)
  at ProxyServer.emit (node:events:527:28)
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/C:/Users/cards/Documents/job-hunt/job-site/node_modules/httpxy/dist/index.mjs:256:16)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
  at tickOnSocket (node:_http_client:764:7)
  at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:827:5)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I would expect that if I had made any changes, I could have broken something, but these errors are right from the start.  I have done some research, and have not found any similar issues to this.

The section of code that is causing me issues is:

```
proxy.proxy.on("proxyReq", (proxyReq, req) => {
    if (!proxyReq.hasHeader("x-forwarded-for")) {
      const address = req.socket.remoteAddress;
      if (address) {
        proxyReq.appendHeader("x-forwarded-for", address);
      }
    }
    if (!proxyReq.hasHeader("x-forwarded-port")) {
      const localPort = req?.socket?.localPort;
      if (localPort) {
        proxyReq.setHeader("x-forwarded-port", req.socket.localPort);
      }
    }
    if (!proxyReq.hasHeader("x-forwarded-Proto")) {
      const encrypted = req?.connection?.encrypted;
      proxyReq.setHeader("x-forwarded-proto", encrypted ? "https" : "http");
    }
  });
```

with the exact line from there error: `proxyReq.appendHeader("x-forwarded-for", address);`

I am using Nuxt version: 3.10.3 and Nitro 2.9.1

Comment: Downgrade to Nitro 2.8.1 resolve issue for me

Answer (score 0):

cnpm i nitropack@2.8.1
This will solve the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might simply want to nuke your package-lock.json and reinstall your packages again. sometimes there can be a package mismatch which could cause that error.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your node.js version to 18 or 20. My own tests on 18.18.2 or 20.10.0 will not continue to report errors.